# How to update the cookies in Httpclient instance which created via HttpClientFactory -C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

By using `HttpClient` directly in, for example, a console application, I can add cookies to the client like so:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
CookieContainer cookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) })
{
    var urlLogin="http://xxxxxx";
    var strContent="key=value"
    await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new StringContent(strContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
    var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(url)).Cast<Cookie>().ToList();//get cookies
    cookie[0].Path = "/"; 
    cookieContainer.Add(cookie[0]); //update the first cookie path to avoid missing cookies in redirect request (302)
    //other action
}
```

But in .NET Core 3.1, I'm using the `HttpClientFactory` to create the `HttpClient` instance, I found out that I could add cookies in a similar way when building the `HttpClient`, but the handler is not accessible in the client instance, therefore I don't know how to update the cookie in the instance.

```
services.AddHttpClient("test1", c =>
            {
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");
                c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);  
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to [HttpClient.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_). In that case you create `HttpRequestMessage` instance for each request separately and then set cookie through [HttpRequestMessage.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers?view=net-5.0). Also you need to keep cookie value itself in some singleton class.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url)
{
    Content = new StringContent("content here", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
};
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "your_value");
await _httpClientFactory.CreateClient().SendAsync(request);
```

So you set cookie per request and don't need to update it in clients.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I didn't fully get your point, could you please give me an example? Will be very appreciated for your help.

Comment: I try in this approach, but it doesn't work. In the 1st part of my code, I got the cookies after posting credentials, then I updated the path of the cookie to avoid cookie issue in the next get request.

Comment: @WoodYang *Also you need to keep cookie value itself in some singleton class.* So workflow should be like this:`1.` you exchange credentials to some token `2.` you put the token into some storage not related to `HttpClient` at all (for instance `IMemoryCache`) `3.` then in all subsequent requests you get the token from the cache and put into each `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: Appreciated for your suggestions. Finally I resolved the issue in a way not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was resolved:

1. Create a static variable

> ```
> public class ScopedVars
>   {
>       public static HttpClientHandler staticHandler { get; set; } = new 
>       HttpClientHandler();
>   }
> ```

2. In Setup, register it

> `services.AddScoped<ScopedVars>();`

3. Add httpclient

> services.AddHttpClient("TEST", c =>   {
> c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
> c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
> 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");        c.Timeout =
> TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);      }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_
> =>ScopedVars.staticHandler);

4. In the service layer

> private HttpClientHandler _handler;   public
> TestService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ScopedVars
> scopedHandler)    {
> _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;         _handler = ScopedVars.staticHandler;    }

5. In a specific task

> CookieContainer cookieContainer = _handler.CookieContainer;   using
> (HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("TEST"))     {
> //XXXX;     }

Since I just run it as QuartzNet task, no need to worry about the multiple request.